# What happens to "+= operator" when its assigned to a empty list in python?

Tags: python

```py
results=[]
for x in range(5):
    results += '$' 
print(results)
```

output : `['$', '$', '$', '$', '$']`

This code behaves differently from typical `+=` operator.  As you can see here it has generated a list with the `$` string inside it.

It's not equal to what we think `results = results + '$'`.  This code will throw you an error.

Can you describe what is going on this code?

Comment: The output clearly shows what happens when you use `+=` with a list and a string... If you want a more detailed explanation, a quick search on google reveals [this](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/559a2e9576b8fec400000392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lists, `+=` is equivalent to `.extend()`. Since a string is an iterable, this works.

`+` however is only defined to allow combining 2 lists together.